# JWPlayer 6 transparent background HTML5

Tags: jwplayer

I upgraded jwplayer from 5.10 to 6.9; I was able to change the player background to transparent by changing the background in the jwplayer.js (5.10) to tansparent

```
background: "transparent no-repeat center center"
```

and also used:

```
wmode = 'transparent'
```

Worked great.  Did the same in jwplayer.js 6 and jwplayer.html5.js changed background and backgroundColor, but had no luck.  I also tried custom skin with transparent background.

Has anyone had success in changing the background to transparent from black.
Here is the player code:

```
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            file: myvideo,
            image: imagename,
            width: "100%",
            autostart: true,
            backcolor: 'transparent',
            wmode: 'transparent',
            aspectratio: "4:3",
            ga: {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you have a link to where you tried this vs JW5?

Comment: Thank you Ethan, I sent the link by email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under:

file: myvideo,

Add:

primary: ‘flash’,

Comment: yes it will make it transparent, but is it possible to use HTML5 with transparent background ?

Comment: JW7 now uses CSS for everything, so you might be able to make it transparent using CSS.